# Reaction of Glucose + NaOH + PVP

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, precipitation

I'm trying to synthesize of silver particles by using glucose as reducing agent, PVP as dispersant, and NaOH as pH control. Before adding silver nitrate solution, I've produced a solution which is combination of glucose, PVP and NaOH in distilled water.

In the polymer solution, I see that the color changes, from colorless to dark orange/brown solution. Is there any reaction that occurs in the polymer solution which contains glucose, PVP, and NaOH due to the changes of color?

I know from researching that the solution is expected to turn yellow when glucose and sodium hydroxide are mixed, which I observe, but I do not understand why the solution changes to darkish orange to brown when PVP is added?